# What is portProxy.bin and why is it sucking/eating/using up my CPU?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, vpn, cpu, activity-monitor

Through today, portProxy.bin has been eating up my CPU, constantly using about 60% and making the fans in my computer whizz up.

I'm guessing it might be connected to my VPN use, but now I haven't been running any VPNs for some hours and portProxy has still been staying at around 60% CPU usage.

[image]

I use Cisco AnyConnect to access my schools private network and [Disconnect](https://disconnect.me) to block trackers and hide my location. Sometimes I forget to disable Disconnect before trying to connect through Cisco AnyConnect, but then AnyConnect can establish a connection and I'm reminded I have Disconnect running. Could this have something to do with it?

Thank you.

Comment: Im guessing that you havent fully quit the vpn app. Try killing the process by clicking it then pressing the x button in activity monitor, right under the close tab button and the minimize button (top left)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't figured out what portProxy.bin is or why it was hogging my CPU, so if you know this, please edit and replace this text with an explanation.

I did a restart and that corrected the problem.

Comment: Note to self: Always do a restart before posting to Q/A forums...